# How can I determine the version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on a client computer?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have an application that needs to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly (nothing crazy, just simple writing to worksheets).
At compile time, I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.  I have Office 2013 installed and everything works as expected.

But that's all irrelevant in terms of if the client can use it.

How can I programatically determine the version of Interop.Excel the user has installed?  **Once I know what version they have, how can I then load those assemblies at runtime to gain access to the Interop objects?**  If the user has, for example, Interop.Excel 14.0 installed, does that mean they definitely have Excel installed too?  How should I check for which version of Excel is installed?

I know the user needs Office installed in order to use Interop.Excel objects, so does that mean I need to be checking both the Office version as well as the Interop assembly version?

We plan to support Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013.

In short -- How do I cover all of my bases here?

There are plenty of questions out there about Interop.Excel but nothing that has made it clear to me:

a) What I need to check for on the client computer

b) How I do those checks through reflection(avoid registry lookup)

Thanks.

Comment: Many misconceptions about this.  It is version 15, your program won't run with anything else.  The Office version might be different, not terribly healthy, use the Application.Version property.

Comment: If you want to target Excel 2007 and above then you should reference the v12.0 Interop.  If the user has a later version of Excel (and therefore Interop), these are forward compatible.

Comment: @HansPassant So even if the API calls I am making are available in Interop.Excel 14, my program won't work if it is built against Interop.Excel 15?

Are there any links/sources  you can provide for either finding the Interop version or the Office version?

Also, any thoughts on CharlesMager's comment?

Comment: @CharlesMager So what I should do is:

1) Build against v.12.0 interop
2) Check excel version.
3) If excel version is 2007 or later, assume I am good to go?

Is there any possibility of Excel 12.0 being installed without the Interop Assemblies 12.0?

Comment: If you're using .NET 4 and later you can [embed the interop types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx) into your assembly so you don't need the client to have them installed at all.  This is usually enabled by default.

Comment: @CharlesMager Ok, so embedding will take the Interop Assemblies out of the equation, but I still need to check for office, right? At that point, I can just look to find office 2007 or later.

And in the case that I cannot use embed (I think we might be on 3.5), does the process in my previous post make sense?

Thanks again so much for your help with this

Comment: Update -- A colleague with Excel 2010 and Interop 14.0 was able to successfully run my .exe that I built against Interop 15.0.   I am only making very simple API calls in my code..no formatting etc. or anything fancy.  Just writing values to a file.  Wondering if that had anything to do with the success so far..

Now to test 2007...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the user has, for example, Interop.Excel 14.0 installed, does that mean they definitely have Excel installed too?

No, interops are used for marshalling calls from managed programming languages to the unmanaged applications.

> How should I check for which version of Excel is installed?

Typically the windows registry is used to detect the installed Office versions. Note, there can be multiple Office versions installed on the PC. Also you may try to run the Office application programmatically and then check out the [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193301(v=office.15).aspx) property at runtime. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084) for more information.

> We plan to support Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013. In short -- How do I cover all of my bases here?

Use the oldest interop whcih corresponds to the lowest Office version you need to support. Thus, you will be sure that you use methods and properties that are available in all Office versions. Or my embedd interop assemblies (types) into your application. This feature is available when you target .net 4.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

There is much more simple solution here. In my case I need to seperate my code flows due to Excel Interop versions.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
if(oXL.Version.Equals("15.0"))
{
   //bla bla..
}
else if(oXL.Version.Equals("14.0")||oXL.Version.Equals("12.0") || oXL.Version.Equals("11.0"))
{
   //bla bla..
}
```